# Duplicate matlab dyadup in numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to duplicate the dyadup function from Matlab in numpy.  Is there any more efficient way to do that than np.insert()?

```
import numpy as np

def dyadup(a, level=1, even=False):
    if even == False:
        start = 1
        end = len(a) + 1
    else:
        start = 0
        end = len(a)
    x = a
    for l in range(level):
      x = np.insert(x, range(start, end), 0)
    return x
```

Running a quick timing on this with an initial 1024 element array, I come up with a best time of 14.2 usec per loop, which isn't bad, but I'm wondering if it can be made better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way to write this would be:

```
import numpy as np

def dyadup(a, level=1, even=False):
    level += 1
    start = 1 if even else 0
    out = np.zeros(len(a) * level, dtype=a.dtype)
    out[start::level] = a
    return out
```

---

### More detail

Let me break this down a bit.

In python (similar to Matlab), we can refer to or extract regularly-spaced items of something through slicing operations.  For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(10)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [4]: x[::2]
Out[4]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

In [5]: x[1::2]
Out[5]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])

In [6]: x[1::3]
Out[6]: array([1, 4, 7])
```

We can also use this to assign items to the array:

```
In [7]: y = np.zeros(10)

In [8]: y
Out[8]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [9]: y[1::3] = 9

In [10]: y
Out[10]: array([ 0.,  9.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.,  0.])

In [11]: y[1::3] = 4, 5, 6

In [12]: y
Out[12]: array([ 0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  0.,  0.])
```

Therefore, we can do things like:

```
In [13]: data = np.random.random(5)

In [14]: data
Out[14]: array([ 0.05458934,  0.97719278,  0.49670205,  0.87299456,  0.2223557 ])

In [15]: interleaved = np.zeros(len(data) * 2)

In [16]: interleaved[::2] = data

In [17]: interleaved
Out[17]: 
array([ 0.05458934,  0.        ,  0.97719278,  0.        ,  0.49670205,
        0.        ,  0.87299456,  0.        ,  0.2223557 ,  0.        ])
```

For large arrays, this is much more efficient than using `insert`, as `insert` will make copy of the array each time it's called.

---

### Timing

As an example of the timing difference

```
In [2]: data = np.arange(10000)

In [3]: %timeit dyadup(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 33 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit orig_dyadup(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.21 ms per loop
```

Note the micro vs milli.  The new implementation is ~100x faster.

---

### Further Considerations

Also, be careful not to modify your input.  In python `x = a` does not make a copy of `a`.  `x` is the same object, so any modifications to `x` are also modifications of `a`.

In this specific case, `np.insert` makes a copy, so you don't wind up modifying your input, but you would in other cases.

---

One final note, if I'm understanding the intent of your original function correctly, it's incorrect if `level` is greater than 1.

For example:

```
In [5]: orig_dyadup(range(10), 3)
Out[5]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
       0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0])
```

vs

```
In [6]: dyadup(range(10), 3)
Out[6]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,
       0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0])
```

The differences are happening because you're modifying something while iterating over it, but referring to indices of the original item when inserting.  However, I could be misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: A much better implementation!  Thanks!